# Protege Owl: restrictions on individuals

Tags: semantic-web, owl, protege, description-logic

I have a little problem with my ontology!
We work on an ontology which manage a smart home. So we have objects like Tables, Doors, Lamps, .... A object that is smart has:

- an actuator which run an action like open a door for example
- a sensor which gets informations about temperature for example

I have ObjectProperties for ex: hasActuator --> Door hasActuator DoorController

So now, the problem is the individuals! I would like that an object (Door_1 for example) has an actuator DoorController_1 but an other Door (Door_2) can't use the actuator DoorController_1 because he's already use !

How can I treat that? Which restrictions?

If I put hasActuator functional, it's only to say that a object can have only one actuator, but it's not that I want!

Answer (score 3):

### The short solution

It sounds like you're trying to say an entity can't be in use by more than one thing at a time.  This is a candidate for InverseFunctionalProperties.  If you say that

> uses is an inverse functional property
>   door1 uses controller1
>   door1 ≠ door2

Then you can infer that

> not( door1 uses controller1 )

### How it works

Stating that a property *p* is an inverse functional property says that

> **Functional**(p):  **if** p(x,y) & p(x,z) **then** y = z

Stating that a property *p* is inverse function is similar, but says that

> **InverseFunctional**(p): **if** p(x,z) & p(y,z) **then** x = y

So, suppose you have the data:

> uses(door<sub>1</sub>,controller<sub>1</sub>)
>   door<sub>1</sub> ≠ door<sub>2</sub>

Now consider the hypothesis that

> uses(door<sub>2</sub>,controller<sub>1</sub>)

From it and the data, you can derive

> door<sub>1</sub> = door<sub>2</sub>

But from the data we already have

> door<sub>1</sub> ≠ door<sub>2</sub>

and this is a contradiction, so the hypothesis must be false.  Therefore:

> not(uses(door<sub>2</sub>,controller<sub>1</sub>))